# Deal with randomly delayed promises in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Sometimes, in assessments of React projects, I encounter something like this:

```
export default () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => (Math.round(Math.random()) === 0 ? resolve(countries) : reject()), 100);
});
```

To simulate an API that might or might not have a delay.

My question is, when I want to fetch this promise in a React component, specifically in `ComponentDidMount()`, what do I need to do to ensure that the `render()` will wait for this promise to render everything I need? What's the best practice around it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--`render` will render as soon as it's called. Components need to be able to render before their data is available, even if it's just an empty render. Or you can `await`/etc, but that blocks everything, which is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Also: `To simulate an API that might or might not have a delay.` this is not what is being simulated. What is being simulated is a fixed delay after which a promise may or may not encounter an error. To check if your catch errors, presumably.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. A promise is *always* asynchronous (delayed), so you just handle it normally with `then()` and `setState()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to a promise that uses random delay or promises at all. Zero-delay `setTimeout` or instantly resolved promise would produce the same result, though barely visible. The execution of `render` can't be postponed.

Initial rendering will be performed any way. If component state is changed asynchronously, `render` should handle initial state correctly:

```
state = { data: null };

componentDidMount() {
  Promise.resolve('foo').then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}

render() {
  return this.state.data ? (
    <div>{this.state.data}</div>
  ) : (
    'No data'
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do anything. The component should still be able to render while waiting for e.g. some state to be populated by the result of the simulated API call. When the promise resolves, if it sets some state on the component then the component will be re-rendered with the new data.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a piece of state `isLoading` in your component that you set to `false` when the promise has resolved, and use that to render `null` until then.

**Example**

```js
const countries = ["gb", "se"];
const getCountries = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      () => (Math.round(Math.random()) === 0 ? resolve(countries) : reject()),
      2000
    );
  });

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { isLoading: true, error: "", countries: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    getCountries()
      .then(countries => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, countries });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, error: "Fetching countries failed" });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, error, countries } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return null;
    }
    if (error) {
      return <div>{error}</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {countries.map(country => (
          <div key={country}>{country}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store a variable in your state indicated whether or not your promise finished. For that, you can either `await` your promise and set your state or use `.then` and set your state in the function's callback.

A minimal code would look like the following :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        try {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => (Math.round(Math.random()) === 0 ? resolve(countries) : reject()), 100);
            });
            this.setState({ show: true })
        } catch(err){

        }
    }

    render = () => this.state.show ? <div>My content</div> : <div/>
}
```

You can obviously replace the Promise created with the variable you exported and change the rendered component into anything you want.